# MongoDB remove value from array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my users collection I have an array field of ObjectIDs

This is the part in the schema

```
groups: [
  {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Group",
  },
],
```

And the DATA looks like

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63ec9a509c6be6a91771a953"
  },
 
  "groups": [
    {
      "$oid": "6477264d2bcb80a3945f2fc1"
    }
  ],
  
 ....
}
```

I want remove group (objectId) from all the users
for example remove the "6477264d2bcb80a3945f2fc1" from all the users that related to this group

Does the solution is remove one by one or there is a better solution for that

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple updateMany query

```js
db.users.updateMany(
  { groups: ObjectId('6477264d2bcb80a3945f2fc1') },
  { $pull: { groups: ObjectId('6477264d2bcb80a3945f2fc1') } }
);
```

See the docs pages for [updateMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/), [Querying an Array for an Element](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element), and the [pull operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)